# Make draggable element a child of container it's dropped into and still keep it draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have two containers, both droppable , one of them contains draggable div element(child of this container) , how can i drag and drop this div into another container, make it child of container where div is dropped  and keep this div still draggable? Later i will need to drag this element back to it's initial container which should become child again and stay draggable.

I can not make this div to be draggable when i drop it into container.

```
                $(".dropzone").droppable({
                greedy: true,
                accept: ".dragable",
                hoverClass:"highlight",

                drop: function (e, ui) {
                $(ui.draggable).detach().appendTo($(this));
                }


            });

           <section id="mockup3" class="mockup-section mockup-content mockup-section--dark paint-area dropzone" >
                <div class="figConteiner1" style="border:2px black solid">
                    <h2 id="figHeading1 "class="figHeading dropzone changeColor">Naujienos</h2>
                    <figure class="figure resizable dragable">
                        <div class="f-image">
                            <img scr="#">
                        </div>
                        <div id="f-caption1" class="f-caption dropzone">
                            <h3 id="headingH1"class="fcaption-heading1 dropzone changeColor">Naujiena 1</h3>
                            <p id="headingP1"class="pHeading1 dropzone changeColor">tekstas 1</p>
                        </div>
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section id="mockup2" class="mockup-section mockup-content mockup-section--dark paint-area dropzone">
                <div id="blokai">
                    <div id="blokas1" class="blokas resizable dragable dropzone">
                        <img src="blokas1.jpg">
                        <div id="tittle1" class="tittle dropzone changeColor" >Planšetės</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

I need to drag draggable div id="blokas1" to droppable section id="mockup3" make this div child of section and keep it draggable, but now when i drop div draggability disappears.

Any examples is highly appreciated! I'm sorry for my English guys!

Comment: Can you provide some of the HTML markup you are using?